# ¿Cómo ordenar Select2 uno al lado de otro en una sola fila?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, datatables, select2

Estoy utilizando la opción de filtrar datos con datatables. Al momento de mostrar los select2 me salen hacia abajo.
[image]

Quisiera que me salieran uno al lado de otro en una sola fila.
Cabe recalcar que a los select2 los declaro desde js así:

```
  var select = $('<select class="Filtros select2 col-md"><option value="">Seleccionar Todas</option></select><script>$(".Filtros").select2({allowClear: true,theme: "bootstrap",dropddownAutoWidth: false,placeholder: "Selecciona Filtro"});</script>')
```

Adjunto código completo:

```
    return $('#' + dg).DataTable({
    initComplete: function () {
        var Destino = '#prueba'
        this.api().columns([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="Filtros select2 col-md"><option value="">Seleccionar Todas</option></select><script>$(".Filtros").select2({allowClear: true,theme: "bootstrap",dropddownAutoWidth: false,placeholder: "Selecciona Filtro"});</script>')
                .appendTo(Destino)
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

            column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
```

Quisiera que el resultado fuera así Pero con el diseño de los select2
Gracias de Antemano

[image]

Comment: Por defecto, `Select2` tratará de tomar el mismo [ancho del contenedor](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width), aunque puedes tratar de modificarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para distribuir bloques en css se puede usar un bloque flex. Puedes meter los select en un contenedor div con display:flex.
Algo como esto

```
<style>
.fila{
    display:flex;
}
<div class="fila">
    <select>
        <option value="1">opcion1</option>
        <option value="2">opcion2</option>
        <option value="3">opcion3</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="1">opcion1</option>
        <option value="2">opcion2</option>
        <option value="3">opcion3</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="1">opcion1</option>
        <option value="2">opcion2</option>
        <option value="3">opcion3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Con las propiedades css del modelo flexbox y de bloques puedes ya adaptar los anchos, alineaciones y cualquier otro ajuste que necesites
También podrías usar grid, pero si vas a usar distribución unidimensional flex se ajusta perfectamente bien.